# getting value of multiple check boxes inserted using foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a table of check boxes using 6 foeach loops. Following is the output of the table.
[image: output of the table]

I'm passing data retrieved by database to the view to get the names in the above table.In my view I have created the table as follows.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
     <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="team_for_event" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/event/team_for_event" >


      <td>
       <?php foreach($c_list as $n_key){ ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c[]" value="<?php echo $n_key->name; ?>">
            <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
             <br/><br/>
            <?php 
            }?>  
      </td>


      <td>
        <?php foreach($ca_list as $n_key){?>
           <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="ca" name="ca[]" value="ca">
            <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
             <br/><br/>
            <?php 
            }?>   
            </td>

          <td>
          <?php foreach($ta_list as $n_key){?>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="ta" name="ta[]" value="ta">
            <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
             <br/><br/>
            <?php 
            }?>  
            </td>


          <td>
            <?php foreach($se_list as $n_key){?>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="se" name="se[]" value="se">
              <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
             <br/><br/>
            <?php 
            }?>  
            </td>

          <td>
            <?php foreach($ao_list as $n_key){?>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="ao" name="ao[]" value="ao">
              <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
               <br/><br/>
            <?php 
            }?>  
          </td>

          <td>
              <?php foreach($vo_list as $n_key){?>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="vo" name="vo[]" value="vo">
              <?php echo $n_key->name; ?></label></div>
               <br/><br/>
              <?php 
              }?>  
            </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
          </tbody>
```

I want to allow the user to check multiple checkboxes in each foeach loop. In my controller I tried several methods but didn't work. Can Someone help me to write the controller correctly?

Comment: _I want to allow the user to check multiple checkboxes in each foeach loop_ They already can check as many checkboxes as they like. So what is really your question

Comment: Please include controller code - even if it doesn't work.

Comment: can check but how to get the value to the controller?